Why is Jesus called Prince of Peace and not King of Peace considering he was also called Eternal Father?
Isaiah 9:6 says:

For a Child will be born to us, a Son will be given to us; And the
government will rest on His shoulders; And His name will be called
Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God, Eternal Father, Prince of Peace.

Given that Jesus is the Son of God and referred to as the Eternal Father, why is He known as the Prince of Peace rather than the King of Peace?

this relats to  Hezekiah - its an incorrect translation will should be has - Young's Literal Translation - For a Child hath been born to us, A Son hath been given to us, - Jesus himself stated he did not come to bring peace - Do not think that I came to bring peace on the earth; I did not come to bring peace, but a sword. 35″For I came to set a man against his father, and a daughter against her mother, and a daughter-in-law against her mother-in-law; 36 and a man’s enemies will be the members of his household. (Matthew 10:34-36)

This distinction between "prince" and "king" is a feature of modern English, and may not be relevant to the Hebrew. Even in English they have sometimes been synonyms; "Little man, 'must' is not a word to be used to princes" (Elizabeth I of England)

@anothertheory - you quote selectively - Jesus gave peace to His disciples before His ascension, John 14:27, Col 3:15, Phil 4:7.  See also Luke 2:14, 1:79, 19:38

@Dottard apart from John 14 - the others are other peoples words / not Peace about Jesus not supportive at all.  -  Luke 19:27 “But those enemies of mine who did not want me to be king over them—bring them here and kill them in front of me.’ ” -Luke 12:49 -  “I have come to bring fire on the earth, and how I wish it were already kindled!  - etc...  at best contradictory

@anothertheory - you are missing the point - Christ's enemies will be vanquished which creates the only lasting peace possible - inner peace (Ps 119:165, John 14:27, Col 3:15, Phil 4:7), peace between Jews and gentiles (Eph 2:17, Rom 2:10, Heb 12:14) and peace in the kingdom of heaven (Luke 2:14, 1:79, 19:38)

@StephenDisraeli  That's the "a sovereign of any kind" definition of "prince."

@Mary Exactly. That's why it's relevant to think about the Hebrew definition of the word translated as "prince".

@StephenDisraeli More importantly, a Prince or Princess can, historically, be a ruler in their own right without a King or Queen.  That's the difference between a Principality and a Kingdom.  Take Monaco for example: the head of state is Albert II, Prince of Monaco — but, there isn't any "King/Queen of Monaco".  There are many historical reasons why different rulers choose Prince/Princess versus King/Queen, Emperor/Empress or Tzar/Caeser/Kaiser.

The operative word שַׂר, "sar" (translated "prince") in most versions has a much broader meaning of -

Prince, ruler, leader, chief, captain, official, ie, a head person

Thus, the phrase "prince of peace" could just as validly be translated:

ruler/leader of peace (compare Ex 18:21, 25, Num 22:13, etc)
commander of peace (cf Gen 21:22, 26:26, 37:36)
chief captain or official of peace (compare Gen 39:22, 23, 40:2, 3, 4, 9, 20, etc)

Thus, "prince" is not necessary as the translation and could be even misleading.  "Leader/ruler/commander" is probably a better choice in Isa 9:6.
Finally, I notice that שַׂר (sar) is used to describe YHWH Himself in His function as "commander" of the LORD's host/army in Josh 5:15 who is revealed to be (Josh 6:2) YHWH speaking to Joshua.

No, Joshua 5 is the Angel of YHWH who is called sar (the Prince).

@OneGodOneLord - correct and in Josh 6:2 we discover that the Angel of YHWH is YHWH Himself.  We see this very often in the OT.

Joshua 6:2 is the the Angel of YHWH speaking on behalf of Father YHWH because he wields the authority of the Divine Name as the messenger and mediator of YHWH. Even as the only begotten Son of YHWH.

Note that one English meaning of "prince" is "a sovereign of any kind."  Hence Elizabeth I, being a sovereign queen, was also a prince.

Another meaning of "Prince", from the original "Princeps" (via "Princeps Senatus", or "Principal Senator", which is more-or-less the same meaning and reason as "Prime Minister"), is just "first", or "leader", or "most eminent".  Princes or Princesses who are heir to a King or Queen are just that: the first people in line for the throne.  So, "Prince of Peace" can mean both "the leader of Peace", but also "the best at Peace", in a manner that implies a level of merit rather than mere birth-right.

@Chronocidal - agreed.  Our English word, "prince" come from the Latin, principio = first, most important, leader.

correct and in Josh 6:2 we discover that the Angel of YHWH is YHWH Himself - and do we learn in Isaiah 7:10 that Isaiah is Y-H-V-H Himself?

Dottard, could the Angel be likened to YHWH himself speaking, because he was given the divine Name and wields it as God's viceroy or agent? So that when the Angel speaks, it is in every sense God speaking, despite the Angel not actually being God himself?

@OneGodOneLord because he was given the divine Name and wields it as God's viceroy or agent? - this is certainly the best way to understand the similar construction found in Isaiah 7:10

@AviAvraham – In Isaiah 7:10, is YHWH speaking directly through Isaiah as his representative agent or channel?

@AviAvraham – This would give revelation to the passage where Jesus said, "Whoever has seen me has seen the Father". This is a knockout blow to the Trinity.

@OneGodOneLord In Isaiah 7:10, is YHWH speaking directly through Isaiah as his representative agent or channel - G-d is clearly speaking directly through Isaiah here. Which is precisely the same thing occurring in Josh 6:2, making it quite curious why Dottard claims it proves that the angel in Josh 6 is G-d

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The answer by Dottard covers the original Hebrew word used in context, but I feel it’s important to understand the history here, because ‘prince’ did not mean the same thing historically that it does today¹, and it used to be a much more accurate translation as a result of this difference in meaning.
The word ‘prince’ and it’s cognates in other languages actually were (and still are in some languages) used with essentially the same meaning as the Hebrew שַׂר in most of Europe², because the Latin princeps was used as an unofficial title by the Emperors of Rome from Augustus through Carinus. In Latin princeps historically meant ‘first’ or ‘foremost’, but because of this usage as an imperial title it came to be associated with the Emperor and his authority, and thus as a generic for an emperor or ruler over other rulers. As a result of this meaning, the usual Latin translation of Isaiah 9:6 uses princeps as a translation for שַׂר (emphasis mine):

parvulus enim natus est nobis filius datus est nobis et factus est principatus super umerum eius et vocabitur nomen eius Admirabilis consiliarius Deus fortis Pater futuri saeculi Princeps pacis

Similar usage is seen in most other parts of the Bible that talk about Jesus specifically, and in a number of other parts that use שַׂר.
All the way back to the earliest Old English translations of the bible, translations have followed the Latin and that bolded phrase has been translated as ‘Prince of Peace’ because English inherited that Latin meaning. It’s only recently that this confusion has arisen though, because even in Early Modern English, ‘prince’ was still being used in the same sense of a ruler in general and not specifically the offspring of a ruler. The King James Bible translated it in this way, as did other contemporaneous translations.
In more modern times, it’s likely that the persistence of this translation is due to a combination of preserving familiarity (put simply, everyone translates it that way, so translating it that way seems more ‘accurate’ or ‘real’ to many people) and the poetic aspect of it being an alliteration (and thus ‘sounding good’).

1: For an understanding of why the meaning in English shifted, read up on the history of the title ‘Prince of Wales’. The story there is interesting in it’s own right, but that history is also a significant majority of the reason that the word ‘prince’ now means the male offspring of a monarch in English instead of just referring to a monarch or ruler in general.
2: As a concrete example, see Machiavelli’s famous Il Principe, his usage of the Italian equivalent of ‘prince’ is exactly in line with this meaning.

Because Early English Translations were based on the Vulgate Bible
The Vulgate Bible was St. Jerome's Latin Translation that he wrote from 383AD to 404AD. This translation chose Princeps as its translation as opposed to other latin words that may have fit because of its specific cultural meaning during his lifetime.
Princeps vs Dominus vs Rex
Rex is the literal Latin word for "king", but a Rex was not a supreme leader in the context of Ancient Rome.  Rome included many conquered kingdoms where historical monarchies were allowed to continue to rule their own lands under Roman dominion.  So, the Emperor represented the idea of a King of Kings, meaning that the best representation of this idea would have been one of the titles for the Emperor, not that of a king.
By 383AD, Rome was well into the Dominus period in which the Emperor of Rome was the autocratic leader of the empire. However, the early Imperial period called the Princeps period was characterized by the Pax Romana, the longest period of peace in Roman history.  During the time of St. Jerome, the Emperor was a Dominus which is the Latin word of an Autocratic Ruler and represented a period of constant civil war and strife for Rome.  But, during the Pax Romana, the Imperial title was Princeps Civitatis AKA: First Citizen.  The idea of a Princeps would have invoked a number of important meanings to ancient Romans because it represented not just the title of Emperor, but also a time in which the Empire was at peace, back when the Emperors saw themselves as servants of the Empire as opposed to dictators of it.
So, St Jerome probably chose the idea of Princeps here because it was a title that unifies the concept of peace and servitude with supreme rulership.
By the time the Vulgate Bible was translated into English, Rome and its customs had all fallen away and Feudalism took over. Variations of titles like King, Prince, Emperor, etc. were all synonymous terms, where different places preferred different titles.  When John Wycliffe first translated the Vulgate Bible into the (EV) English bible, his goal was to try to translate it verbatim and as directly as possible.  He made sure to just change Latin words to their closest English equivalents with as little modification to the words or grammer as possible because the idea of changing the meaning of the Bible during translation was considered sacrilegious. So, to him, the closest translation of Princeps would have been Prince which was the English word based on the original Latin.  The King James Bible followed suit, and since then, English translators have consistently preferred this translation due to their familiarity with it, even though the idea of Prince has since changed to represent someone under a king as opposed to it's historical meaning as someone over one.

+1. This is a good answer that explains the historical context well!

Repeat from the OP of Isaiah 9:6

For a Child will be born to us, a Son will be given to us; And the government will rest on His shoulders; And His name will be called Wonderful Counselor, Mighty God, Eternal Father, Prince of Peace.

Isaiah 9:6 refers to a future event, which may explain why the term "prince" is more favorable than "king". A prince is the heir, the future promise and is subordinate to the Father.
Why would He also be called the Eternal Father? Dottard has quoted the Jewish Translation of Isaiah 9:6 in his question Isaiah 9:6 Translation: Jewish vs Christian, which is certainly worth considering.

For a child has been born to us, a son given to us, and the authority is upon his shoulder, and the wondrous adviser, the mighty God, the everlasting Father, called his name, "the prince of peace."

